# Find all values of parameter a, when sum of solutions of following equation is 100

Tags: trigonometry, quadratics, parametric

Find all values of parameter $a$, when sum of solutions of following equation is $100$.
$$
 \sin(\sqrt{ax-x^2})=0
$$

I tried to get rid of that $sin$ and there was quadratic equation with two parameters ($a$ and $k$($\pi$$k$)). After that I did pretty much nothing productive. Could you please help me with this equation?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $a\leq0$ then $ax-x^2\geq0$ only when $a\leq x\leq 0$; such $x$-values cannot sum up to $100$. Therefore we may assume $a>0$. Put $x:={a\over2}+y$. Then
$$\sqrt{(a-x)x}=k\pi, \quad k\geq0,$$
translates into
$$y^2={1\over4}\bigl(a^2-(2k\pi)^2\bigr)\ .\tag{1}$$
Assume that
$$2n\pi<a<2(n+1)\pi, \qquad n\geq0\ .$$
Then $(1)$ admits  $2(n+1)$ real solutions $\pm y_k\ne0$ by letting $0\leq k\leq n$. These give rise to $2(n+1)$ corresponding $x$-values
$$x_k^+={a\over2}+y_k,\qquad x_k^-={a\over2}-y_k\ .$$
Their sum is $(n+1)a$, which then enforces $a={100\over n+1}$. We now have to check whether this value is within the bounds assumed for $a$, i.e., whether
$$2n\pi<{100\over n+1}<2(n+1)\pi\ .\tag{2}$$
On the one hand $(2)$ enforces $(n+1)^2>{50\over \pi}\doteq15.9$, hence $n\geq3$. On the other hand $n(n+1)<{50\over\pi}$ is true for $n=3$, but is already violated for $n=4$. It follows that $n=3$ is the only admissible $n$, so that we obtain the only solution $a={100\over n+1}=25$ of the original problem.

I leave the case $a=2n\pi$, $n\geq1$ to you.

Answer (score 1):

hint: notice $x$ belongs $(0,a)$ where $0$ and $a$ both are roots , and if $x=\frac{a}{2}+k$ is a root so is $x=\frac{a}{2}-k$ . now try to look into how many roots does this equation have. assuming $a$ is positive for now , you can use the same logic for negative $a$ as for positive $a$

Comment: Why does $x\in(0,a)$? What about $x=-\frac{a}{2}$?

Comment: Sqrt value becomes negative

Comment: Only if $a>0$. We are not told that is the case.

Comment: Your right i should edit that

Comment: but basic logic of the solution still remains the same